# Java : to avoid NullPointer , initialized a String array

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I do a middleware call as to get an array of `String` as shown:

```
String[] freqwords = MViewer.getWordNames();
```

The issue is that there might be no data available, so any further operations like `freqWords.length`, may result in `NullPointerException`.

So to avoid that I am handling in this below way as shown:

```
if (freqwords == null)
{
  freqwords = new String[0];
}
```

The code is working fine - please let me know if there is any better approach or any negative scenarios with this.

Comment: It's impossible to say if this is ok without looking at the rest of the related code...

Comment: Returning null arrays or collections is indeed a bad practice. Prefer returning empty arrays or collections. And prefer collections over arrays.

Comment: totally agree with you , but cant do anything with existing code .

Comment: Then wrap the method into your own, and make it return an empty array or list, like you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you never need to distinguish the case of `String[0]` from a `null` return value (e.g. if `null` is returned if and only if there is no data available), then this seems like a perfectly reasonable solution.

Comment: You could also end the method early if having a null freqwords means there is nothing useful to say